# reporter.log is not coming under try and catch block

Tags: selenium

Below is the code:

```
try {
    WebElement Link_Logout = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("logoutLink"))); 
    if(Link_Logout.isEnabled()==true)
    {
        Reporter.log("<br>Step Logout: Customer has been logout successfully");
        Link_Logout.click();
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("Login"));
        Reporter.log("<br>Step Logout: Customer has been logout successfully");
    }
} catch(Exception exc) {
    if(exc instanceof WebDriverException || exc instanceof UnhandledAlertException) {
        Reporter.log("<br>Step Logout: Customer has not been logout successfully due to exception");
        System.out.println("The exception thrown here is :" +exc);
    }
}
```

Note: code under try block is executing but reporter.log is not working.

Comment: where are you verifying reporter log? Did you trace and see execution control is coming to Reporter.log statement? Reporter log will be added to TestNg html reports.

Comment: yup I am verifying and control is coming inside the loop, but when checking in HTML, its not reflecting,

Comment: Actually I am using Testng and in Aftermethod I am trying to get the Reporter.log and its not working.

Verified in google group and its an issue, let me know if workaround is there.